# (C#/WPF) Understanding bubbling of mouse events

Tags: c#, wpf

In my quest to understand events in WPF, I have come to a bit of standstill. My goal is to bubble a click event in a Grid inside my View class to MainWindow so I can manipulate it there. This is my attempt so far:

**View.cs**

```
public class View
{
    public UserGrid controlGrid { get; set; }
    public View()
    {
        controlGrid = new UserGrid();
        //Some logic
        controlGrid.MouseLeftButtonUp += new MouseButtonEventHandler(controlGrid.grid_MouseLeftButtonUp);
    }
}
```

**UserGrid.cs**

```
public class UserGrid : Grid
{
    public event MouseButtonEventHandler GridMouseLeftButtonUp;
    public void grid_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {

        GridMouseLeftButtonUp?.Invoke(this, e);
        e.Handled = false;
    }
}
```

**MainWindow.cs**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public View mainView { get; set; }
    public MainWindow()
    {
        mainView = new View();
        DataContext = mainView;
        mainView.controlGrid.GridMouseLeftButtonUp += new MouseButtonEventHandler(controlGrids_MouseLeftButtonUp);

    }
    private void controlGrids_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Some logic
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Now, from my understanding what I would expect to happen is the following: Clicking on the `UserGrid` causes the `grid_MouseLeftButtonUp()` function to fire, invoking the event `GridMouseLeftButtonUp`. `MainWindow` has a handler that handles the `GridMouseLeftButtonUp` event, and triggers when the event is invoked.

However, what ends up happening is that the `grid_MouseLeftButtonUp` function in the `UserGrid` fires, but not the function in `MainWindow`. I'm not sure why.

I'm obviously missing something here, can anyone help me understand this a bit better?

Comment: in wpf you don't use the raw event keyword alone, look for RoutedEvents instead

Comment: on the top level, you don't need to manage the control where the event comes from. Change that <mainView.controlGrid.GridMouseLeftButtonUp  > to <MouseLeftButtonUp += >. You can also use snoop to follow the events

Comment: and you can also delete <controlGrid.MouseLeftButtonUp += new MouseButtonEventHandler(controlGrid.grid_MouseLeftButtonUp);> and the code in the UserGrid if you don't do anything special

Comment: Thanks for both of your answers. 

@sam  I reused much of the code in this first example [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/how-to-create-a-custom-routed-event), renamed the `Click` method to `OnMouseLeftButtonDown` and added a public AddHandler event to access the protected `OnMouseLeftButtonDown` method. In the AddHandler method (`MouseLeftButtonDown += new RoutedEventHandler(OnMouseLeftButtonDown);`) I get the following error: No overload for `OnMouseLeftButtonDown` matches delegate `RoutedEventHandler`. Any ideas?

Comment: @GCamel In regard to your second comment, how would the ControlGrid know that I left-clicked without that line of code? Is it not necessary for triggering the `grid_MouseLeftButtonDown` method?

Comment: no it is not necessary, control fire events even if you do not write handlers - give a try with a simple app- mainWindow with a grid, add MouseUp override in the Main and you will get the event (if bubble one) -  take care also that "empty" control like grid do not fire event if you don't set BackgroundColor="Transparent"

Comment: Thanks for your comments @GCamel, your comments made me realize I had misunderstood a lot of how events worked. I resolved the issue!